# import and develop an ionic project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a Ionic project.I build the project successfully`ionic build android`Then I import the folder `platform/android` in android studio as the answer told me on Internet.But the answer is about ionic1.The folder `platform/android/assets` in an Ionic2 project is totally different from an Ionic1 project.There is no any html pages in assets folder but index.html.
Does anyone know the right way to develop an Ionic2 project in android studio?

Comment: why to import in studio?you can build in command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build a project using Ionic 2, it bundles all the code into a file called `main.js` using Browserify, which you can find in `/assets/www/build/main.js`. This process was not included in Ionic 1, hence the difference.

With this scenario, I am not sure how to get it to work with Android Studio, because the Ionic project is not an Android Studio project and disabling the bundling process does not seem like a great idea.

Is there a reason why you are using Android Studio to develop your Ionic app? Why not use an editor or IDE that is more specialized for editing web apps? For example, Ionic has a great integration with Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My job is developing an app by myself. I did not do work like that so I just search on the intenet. Now I know the difference of  Native App and  Hybrid App . Thanks again.

Comment: If I use Visual Studio how to build into aandroid app

Comment: @Prasad Have a look at [Getting Started guide](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic/#configAndroid) on the Visual Studio website.